# Git best practice for a cross-repository folder (TortoiseGit)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm pretty sure this has been answered before, but I can't find a good one for me. Whats the best way to integrate a repository, which should be up-to-date, in another? This repository should exist in a few other repositories. I've read about

- subtrees
- submodules

I tried submodules but for a git newcomer like me, it seams very complicated. In my idea, when I pull the repository, the sub-repo should also update itself. Is there another, easy way I have missed?

Example: The repository **Source_Global** should be in repository **MyFramework** as well as in **MyGameEngine**.

I'm working with TortoiseGit on Windows.

Comment: If possible maybe consider using NuGet for dependencies. If not, submodules seem to be the best alternative. However, as you say it is cumbersome, as you then need to check out a new version of the submodule and build it every time you want to update it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the technologies you're using? In many cases, a package manager/dependency tool is what you're looking for, e.g. NuGet as mentioned above, or npm for Node.js, or Bower for web front-end projects...

Comment: It's delphi code from our own repository, so a packet manager wouldn't help.

Comment: Working with subtree is the best solution in my opinion. the cons are that Git Extensions does not handle it actually so it must be managed using the command line (that can be a problem if are not used to use it). Here's a tutorial about it: https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a few years since the last answer, so I think it's worth revisiting this question.

**Submodules**

This appears to be the most widespread way to handle your situation (at least according to [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=git%20subtree,git%20submodule)). But there are plenty of complaints online about how it's difficult to use. To wit:

- You have to be careful to keep your submodule state clean and avoid making corrupted commits
- A repo with a submodule is difficult to clone
- You can't see submodule commit history in the parent repo

**Subtrees**

I think the Git implementation for subtrees is much more user-friendly than submodules. Subtrees are affected by none of the three issues I listed above. But TortoiseGit [still](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/2255) doesn't support creating, pulling, or pushing subtrees. (You *can* view and commit to them, though.) You can try Atlassian Sourcetree as a substitute, but that has its own drawbacks.

I think of subtrees as the talented but neglected sibling of submodules.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar question, and found that subtrees are likely the best solution in Git.  However, at present subtree support is absent from TortoiseGit, so you'll need to use the command line to make use of that feature.

Also note that neither submodules nor subtrees allow importing *a portion* of one repository into another (which was important to me).

The solution for me (which may not help you), was to use Subversion (and TortoiseSVN) until subtree support is better integrated and documented for Windows.